# Is the transition electric quadrupole or magnetic dipole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

If a nucleus makes a transition from 0$^+$ ground state to 2$^+$ excited state, then will the transtion have E2 character, or M1? Or partly, both? Should the matrix elements of both E2 and M1 be determined for such transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only be E2. Your initial and final angular momenta are 0 and 2 respectively. You can not couple 0 and 1 to get 2 --- the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient is 0. But there are other transitions (like ^{135}Cs(5/2+) --> ^{135}Cs(7/2+) where both are possible because 5/2 can be coupled with 1 to get 3/2, 5/2 or 7/2, and with 2 to give 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2 or 9/2. The matrix elements of both E2 and M1 (and all others that contribute) are determined for such transitions.